# desktop sharing with java rmi

Tags: java, desktop, rmi

i want to write a java rmi application which the server has the ability to share its desktop between  several clients. what is its main method to share desktop? is there any where that i find a good sample code for this application?

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.awt.Robot` (an example [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84094.html)) on the server side to simulate mouse/keyboard events and invoke them from client side.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
```